# Deploying CAM I get Internal error occurred: admission webhook error

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

I'm getting this error code deploying CAM helm chart:

```
Internal service error : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = release cam failed: Internal error occurred: admission webhook "trust.hooks.securityenforcement.admission.cloud.ibm.com" denied the request: Deny "mycluster.icp:8500/services/icam-bpd-cds:3.1.0.0-x86_64", no matching repositories in ClusterImagePolicy and no ImagePolicies in the "services" namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via cmd line:

```
kubectl edit clusterimagepolicies $(kubectl get clusterimagepolicies --no-headers | awk ‘{print $1}’)
```

Inspect the list of -name entries.  Should already be something in there for

```
mycluster.icp:8500/*
```

You can try adding an explicit

```
-name mycluster.icp:8500/services/icam-bpd-cds:*
```

entry and *wq* to write and quit and see if that helps.